# Create date table of every second between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I need to create a table of every second between two input dates

eg between 01/01/2015 00:00:01  and 05/01/2016 00:00:00

So a 3m row expected output that looks like this:

[image]

Does this need a CLR? function. Does anyone have any examples?

Comment: CLR or CTE? You certainly don't need a CLR. A recursive CTE maybe...

Comment: What's the upper limit to the number of seconds?

Comment: i need 4-5 years so probably no more that 200M (157,680,000 for 5 years)

Comment: Ok, I had to expand to Tally to 1 billion rows then :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Tally will be (by far) the fastest method here. Though you can do this with an rCTE as well, if you are going to be doing this for 100,000's (or even millions) of seconds, it's going to get slow fast.

```sql
DECLARE @StartDate datetime2(0) = '2020-01-01T17:00:00',
        @EndDate datetime2(0) = '2020-03-02T01:30:45';

WITH N AS (
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS (
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF_BIG(SECOND,@StartDate,@EndDate)+1)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1  AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2,  N N3,  N N4, N N5, N N6, N N7, N N8, N N9) --Up to 1B rows (a little under under 32 years)
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND,T.I,@StartDate)
FROM Tally T;
```

Comment: (10,000,000 rows affected) - this seems to stop at 10M rows which isnt quite a year.  Is this a setting that is not configure correctly on my DB side?

Comment: @AndusM note I [updated](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65106502/2) the answer after your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65106384/create-date-table-of-every-second-between-two-dates/65106502?noredirect=1#comment115102742_65106384). At the time I wrote the answer, I didn't know you needed over 100M rows, as you hadn't replied.